# Can you win with two creepers when the goal only has one creeper?

Tags: fluxx

In various flavors of Fluxx, there are Creepers; they all say "You cannot win if you have this card in front of you, unless a card says otherwise." In Cthulhu Fluxx, there are frequently Goals that have creepers on them.

If there's a Goal out there that has a Creeper and a Keeper on it, and I have the right Keeper, the right Creeper, and one other Creeper, can I win?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No**. The Goal will specify which Creepers are allowed for that Goal to succeed. Any surplus Creepers do not have their "unless a card says otherwise" triggered, so you cannot win.